# Best practice for text size dimen declarations

Tags: android, android-resources

I'd like to declare some dimensions for naming some common text sizes in my app.  Are there any agreed upon standards or recommended best practices for the various res categories?  Or, have there been any clever solutions for basing common text sizes dynamically at runtime on the current system default?  For example, default text size is considered normal text.  A smaller size is declared for minor text/descriptions, a slightly larger size for minor headlines, a much larger size for major headlines, etc.

Answer (score 3):

In our code, We often set 3 or 4 steps for text size to keep it looks uniform, such as

```
<dimen name="textview_small_size">11sp</dimen>
<dimen name="textview_middle_size">13sp</dimen>
<dimen name="textview_big_0_size">21sp</dimen>
<dimen name="textview_big_1_size">30sp</dimen>
```

And for perfect UI appearance, You should define separate dimens in different DPIs and screen size like values-sw800dp-large-port.

So, just set the text size to make it looks perfect and keep a uniform rule. 
There is no difference between set size in xml and in runtime, there're basically the same.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a late answer but I feel it would still be helpful.

For different screen sizes, it is recommended to use dedicated resource files as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSWQuali).

However, structuring content in a given resource file also proves useful (The same conventions can be used for text and dimension resources). Here, I use conventions similar to [material colors](https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-palette)
[image]

```
<resources>
  <dimen name="normal_100">16dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="normal_125">20dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="normal_150">24dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="normal_175">28dp</dimen>

  <dimen name="normal_200">32dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="normal_225">36dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="normal_250">40dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="normal_275">44dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

This greatly increases reusability and avoids declaring write-once-use-once dimension literals like

```
<dimen name="home_screen_banner_textLeftPadding">16dp</dimen>
```

For a complete descriptive article, see [this](https://medium.com/@june.pravin/dimensions-by-conventions-92b422e2216e).

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain different values folder for different device size and you can mention your text size in those values folder. Android will take appropriate text size as per device. For reference you can check [pdf](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-8An4Rd1nmKTHpGUUVXcXF1Zm8/edit) provided by GOOGLE IO. You will find how they are suggesting for using dimens.xml for different devices of android. For Example see the structure given below:

```
res/values/dimens.xml

res/values-small/dimens.xml

res/values-normal/dimens.xml

res/values-xlarge/dimens.xml
```

For Example

```
In values/dimens.xml    
<dimen name="text_size">10dp</dimen>

In values-xlarge/dimens.xml
<dimen name="text_size">20dp</dimen>
```

Comment: Your link in broken.
[Here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-8An4Rd1nmKTHpGUUVXcXF1Zm8/edit) is a working link to the same document.